# How to open files from visual studio's 2013 Source Control Explorer in Notepad++

Tags: visual-studio-2013, source-control-explorer

What i want to get: after double click on file in Source Control Explorer, connected to TFS, it must be opened in external text editor ( like Notepad++ ).

Problem: 'View with..' menu item is missing, so i don't know how to change default editor to files listed in Source Control Explorer.

[image: img]

Apps installed: Visual Studio 2013 + Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013 + TFS 2010 on server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the Power Tools...

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f

... and then in my context menu "Advanced" --> "View With" appeared.